# Moving density template (image) to new locations with Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a number of points, each one has the same density (non-uniform) around it. I've created a template (image representing density) for one of the points ('point1'), and would like to move that around to the other points (e.g. move the image from around point1 to around point2.

Is this possible?

```
var Point_Density = ee.Image("users/bucklandtheresa/DensityTemplate")
var point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([31.364499798229676, -10.72313045083073])
var point2 = ee.Geometry.Point([30.99431863153101, -10.887990272110613])
Map.addLayer(point1, {}, 'point1')
Map.addLayer(point2, {}, 'point2')
Map.addLayer(Point_Density, {}, 'Point Density')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an existing image and you want to change where it is understood to be located on the globe, [`ee.Image.changeProj`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-changeproj) can do that.

Here's a function that can translate your image from `point1` to `point2`:

```js
// Translate the image pixels such that the pixel under srcPoint
// will instead be under dstPoint.
function translateImageAtPoint(srcPoint, dstPoint, image) {
  var imageProjection = image.projection();
  
  // Get the x,y coordinates of the points *in the image's projection*.
  // Using that projection means that the image remains undistorted in
  // that projection.
  var srcCoords = srcPoint.transform(imageProjection).coordinates();
  var dstCoords = dstPoint.transform(imageProjection).coordinates();
  
  // Construct a projection whose coordinates are translated
  // by the same amount as the points.
  var translatedProjection = imageProjection.translate(
    dstCoords.getNumber(0).subtract(srcCoords.getNumber(0)),
    dstCoords.getNumber(1).subtract(srcCoords.getNumber(1)));
  
  return image.changeProj(imageProjection, translatedProjection);
}


Map.addLayer(
  translateImageAtPoint(point1, point2, Point_Density),
  {},
  'Translated',
);
```

Note that I wrote this to keep the image's proportions and orientation under the image's own coordinate system (projection). Depending on circumstances, you might want to do something different; the general principle is that it will be translated but not distorted in *the projection called `imageProjection` here*. For example, in your case where the image is in EPSG:4326, it will become less square (in physical terms) if moved towards the poles, since degrees of longitude (your x coordinates) correspond to shorter distances than degrees of latitude (your y coordinates), the closer the longitude is to a pole. If this distortion is a significant factor for your application, you should choose a projection which has a similar scale at the two points — either by creating the image in that projection, or explicitly using a projection other than `image.projection()` in this transformation.

Comment: Thank you! I'm hoping to keep the image ~2km*2km wherever I move it, do you know what projection it would be a good idea to create the image in?

Comment: @Emma There's no projection that can do that everywhere — that's the nature of projections. Which one is best depends on which types of distortion are tolerable and where on the globe you're working. You can reuse the same image data in another projection by using the other projection (not just translated) in the second argument to `changeProj`, but you still have to pick an output projection that is good for your region of interest.

Comment: But is there something I can do to make the density accurate in km? For example, rescaling the projection to take into account the conversion between latitude and longitude in the new location.

Comment: @Emma Look at `ee.Image.pixelArea()`. It gives you an image whose values are the area of each pixel (in any projection) so that you can multiply a density value by area to get a result you can sum over, independent of pixel shapes.